# How did Lord Shiva get his Damaru and leather for His Damaru?

Tags: shiva, puranas

Since Shiva was the first living entity in the universe followed by Bhagwaan Vishnu and  Brahma, according to many puranas, I have several questions about Shiva Bhagwaan and even after searching many times, i could not find answers to my questions.  My questions are

1. When and how did Shiva attain his damaroo?
2. Where did He get the leather for his damaru?

I have found answers for all weapons of Vishnu. Can someone provide an answer?

Comment: what do you mean by "leather for Damaru"?

Comment: Interesting question!