# Importance of using ḍamaru-hasta and trident in Lord Shiva

Tags: shiva

Lord Shiva using ḍamaru-hasta and Trident almost we aware of it. However,

1. When the ḍamaru are using by Shiva that means in which situation he is using the Damaru-hasta
2. Who is given or when he is have that?
3. Importance of ḍamaru-hasta for human to be considered in their life?

Comment: This is an English language site. transliterate Tamil words into English. It is unclear what you are exactly asking . Please clarify. Give some context to the question. What stars are you talking about?

Comment: It is not Hindi, it was Sanskrit. Did you see any Tamil words? Sanskrit should also be transliterated just like Tamil.

Comment: You mean what is the importance of Damaru Hasta like Mudra in our lives? And who gave the Damaru to Lord Shiva?

Comment: Yes absolutely... I hope you got it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How did Lord Shiva get his Damaru and leather for His Damaru?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/17609/5212). Remove the part which is already asked in that question i.e how he go Dhamaru.And what importance of Damaru are you looking for in human life?

Comment: Yes. questions are similar however No answers are there.